# UITapGestureRecognizer with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UISearchBar on my main ViewController. Below this search bar is a map so I figure that I need a second ViewController specifically for searching.

My current approach is to add a uitapgesturerecognizer to the search bar on my main ViewController so that **when the user clicks on the search bar, they are seamlessly redirected to the second view**.

My code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(segueToSearch:)];

[searchBar addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

and

```
- (IBAction)segueToSearch:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"about to segue");
    }
```

This works when I do `singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2` but obviously I want it to work with one tap.

Is my approach valid and if so what is wrong or is there another way to do this?

Comment: so let me get this straight, you want to show a UISearchBar to users and when they click on it you want to take them to another page. Is that about right? So what's the point of search bar? Might as well create a UIButton called "Click to Search here"???

Comment: or, just add a button with a searchbar like image, and perform your segue. Wonder what you are trying to achieve without using UISearchBarDelegate methods

Comment: bad app design comes to mind

Comment: @SamBudda Search bar is there for clarity and because I am also using it to display the current state of the app. Basically, I am trying to achieve exactly what the Yelp app achieves with their search bar over their map.  I don't see how this is "bad app design".

Comment: @scottmrogowski I’ve noticed you’ve been using the cocoa tag for your Cocoa Touch questions, but the cocoa tag is for Cocoa/OS X. Use the cocoa-touch tag instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`UISearchBar` has a `UISearchbarDelegate` protocol which you can use to get notified when the users attempts to edit the inputfield.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   // here you open the viewController
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others mentioned in the comment you would be better of dedicating a separate scene for your search as it doesn't make much sense here. Maybe you could just make a button that takes you to the next scene. Or maybe a textfield that looks like a search bar. Search bar when you are not using search would be pointless.

If you still want to have some action to be performed on single tap of search bar, you could make `self` (or whichever object) as delegate of the search bar and implement the below method to `return NO` after you are done with changing to the new view controller.

`- BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

You could write your code (that you had planned on writing in the gesture's selector) in this method and `return NO`.

This doesn't make it recognize your single tap gesture recognizer though.

Comment: +1 for same answer as above. Had to choose one though and Karl's was a bit clearer